# System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: Access is denied?

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient, impersonation, asp.net-core-webapi

I implemented two aspnet core webapi services. The first service (.net core) calls the second service (.net framework 461) using restsharp:

```
 public static RestResponse Execute(this IRestClient client, IRestRequest request)
    {
        var taskCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource();
        client.ExecuteAsync(request, r => taskCompletion.SetResult(r));
        return (RestResponse)(taskCompletion.Task.Result);
    }
```

Notice that the task is called synchronously on purpose hence the `.Result` in the code. Also this method is called impersonated using the authenticated user!

Both services are hosted in IIS and configured to use Kerberos windows authentification. Both services are run as administrators. Only the first service uses https the other one only http but both use the same domain as the binding url. Now when I debug both services on my local development environment everything works  just fine. Moving the code to IIS I get the following exception:

[image]

The error occurs when calling the above method `Execute`. I have checked the event log if maybe Kerberos has a problem but can't see any Kerberos related issues. In my log files I can also see that the second service is not running any code, the call does not get that far.

Could someone please point me in the right direction. I have no idea what might cause this issue.

**Update**
I tried to call both services with Firefox from outside the server which worked a few times, but after a reboot of the server it didn't work any more. Very strange behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned out that the exceptions we have got were due to a wrong assignment of  service princal names to the two services. Both services were running on the same machine which seduces us to use the same SPN for both services but with different ports. This was a bad idea (don't do that!) and led to all kind of weird exceptions like the WebException "Access is denied".

Assigning each service with an unique SPN solved the problem and the exceptions disappeared.